# Fill Dates Between Two Event Timestamps Formatted as POSIXct

Tags: r, purrr, lubridate

I have a dataframe containing the start and end timestamps of events. I would like to create a sequence of timestamps to fill the dates between these events. Here's the structure of my data:

```
dat <- structure(list(event_id = 1:2,
                      start_time = structure(c(1617346800,1617348000),
                                             class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                      end_time = structure(c(1617347400, 1617348300),
                                           class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")),
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

What I'm hoping to do is lengthen the data frame so there are as many rows as there are minutes between the two events. So you'd end up with something like this:

```
final <- structure(list(event_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), start_time = structure(c(1617346800, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1617348000, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    end_time = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1617347400, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 1617348300), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    record_time = c("2/4/2021 7:00", "2/4/2021 7:01", "2/4/2021 7:02", 
    "2/4/2021 7:03", "2/4/2021 7:04", "2/4/2021 7:05", "2/4/2021 7:06", 
    "2/4/2021 7:07", "2/4/2021 7:08", "2/4/2021 7:09", "2/4/2021 7:10", 
    "2/4/2021 7:11", "2/4/2021 7:12", "2/4/2021 7:13", "2/4/2021 7:14", 
    "2/4/2021 7:15", "2/4/2021 7:16", "2/4/2021 7:17", "2/4/2021 7:18", 
    "2/4/2021 7:19", "2/4/2021 7:20", "2/4/2021 7:21", "2/4/2021 7:22", 
    "2/4/2021 7:23", "2/4/2021 7:24", "2/4/2021 7:25")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

So far what I've come up with is creating a dataframe of the full sequence:

```
timeline <- as.POSIXct(
                  seq.POSIXt(from = min(dat$start_time),
                       to = max(dat$end_time), by = "min"))
```

From here, I'm stuck as to how to join the two. Using a `for` loop I can make a list of sequences, though at that point, I'm still not sure how to get both these things together (also, I'm sure it could be done better with `purrr` but I'm not good with `purrr` yet).

```
event_timelines <- list()

for (row in 1:nrow(dat)) {
  event_timelines[[row]] <- seq.POSIXt(from = dat[row,]$start_time,
                                       to = dat[row,]$end_time,
                                       by = "min")
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `dplyr` approach (with `fuzzyjoin`).

```r
library(dplyr)

timerange <- range(unlist(dat[,c("start_time", "end_time")]))
attributes(timerange) <- attributes(dat$start_time)

tibble(record_time = seq(timerange[1], timerange[2], by = "min")) %>%
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_full_join(
    dat,
    by = c("record_time" = "start_time", "record_time" = "end_time"),
    match_fun = list(`>=`, `<=`)
  ) %>%
  group_by(event_id) %>%
  mutate(
    start_time = start_time[c(1, rep(NA, n()-1))],
    end_time = end_time[c(rep(NA, n()-1), 1)]
  ) %>%
  arrange(record_time) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  print(n=99)
# # A tibble: 26 x 4
#    record_time         event_id start_time          end_time           
#    <dttm>                 <int> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#  1 2021-04-02 07:00:00        1 2021-04-02 07:00:00 NA                 
#  2 2021-04-02 07:01:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  3 2021-04-02 07:02:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  4 2021-04-02 07:03:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  5 2021-04-02 07:04:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  6 2021-04-02 07:05:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  7 2021-04-02 07:06:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  8 2021-04-02 07:07:00        1 NA                  NA                 
#  9 2021-04-02 07:08:00        1 NA                  NA                 
# 10 2021-04-02 07:09:00        1 NA                  NA                 
# 11 2021-04-02 07:10:00        1 NA                  2021-04-02 07:10:00
# 12 2021-04-02 07:11:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 13 2021-04-02 07:12:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 14 2021-04-02 07:13:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 15 2021-04-02 07:14:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 16 2021-04-02 07:15:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 17 2021-04-02 07:16:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 18 2021-04-02 07:17:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 19 2021-04-02 07:18:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 20 2021-04-02 07:19:00       NA NA                  NA                 
# 21 2021-04-02 07:20:00        2 2021-04-02 07:20:00 NA                 
# 22 2021-04-02 07:21:00        2 NA                  NA                 
# 23 2021-04-02 07:22:00        2 NA                  NA                 
# 24 2021-04-02 07:23:00        2 NA                  NA                 
# 25 2021-04-02 07:24:00        2 NA                  NA                 
# 26 2021-04-02 07:25:00        2 NA                  2021-04-02 07:25:00
```

The reason I chose to use `fuzzyjoin` is because `POSIXt` are floating-point `numeric`-like with some attributes, and sometimes (due to general computing challenges, see [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), "floating-point equality" is not always guaranteed. In this case, `fuzzyjoin` is doing a range-based join, effectively is `record_time` between `start_time` and `end_time`.

Comment: Your answer works as does another one given at about the same time. How will I decide which one is the best?!

Comment: It's all relative. The solutions all have their merit (imo), and none of us appear to be starving for rep ;-), so pick the one that fits best into your flow and will be the most robust to what you expect in your data. (That is, sometimes floating-point safeguards like mine may not be necessary if you're confident in your data. \*shrug\*)

Comment: The reason I ended up choosing this answer was because it still worked even if events overlapped. This results in duplicate timestamps, but that ends up working in my favor for plotting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

A way using `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

Expand the sequence using `complete`, `fill` the `NA`'s with previous non-NA values and use `replace` to adjust the output to make it similar to expected output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(record_time = start_time) %>%
  complete(record_time = seq(min(start_time), max(end_time), by = '1 min')) %>%
  fill(everything()) %>%
  mutate(event_id = replace(event_id, record_time >  end_time, NA),
        across(c(start_time, end_time), ~replace(., . != record_time, NA)))


#           record_time event_id          start_time            end_time
#1  2021-04-02 07:00:00        1 2021-04-02 07:00:00                <NA>
#2  2021-04-02 07:01:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#3  2021-04-02 07:02:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#4  2021-04-02 07:03:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#5  2021-04-02 07:04:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#6  2021-04-02 07:05:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#7  2021-04-02 07:06:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#8  2021-04-02 07:07:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#9  2021-04-02 07:08:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#10 2021-04-02 07:09:00        1                <NA>                <NA>
#11 2021-04-02 07:10:00        1                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:10:00
#12 2021-04-02 07:11:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#13 2021-04-02 07:12:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#14 2021-04-02 07:13:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#15 2021-04-02 07:14:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#16 2021-04-02 07:15:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#17 2021-04-02 07:16:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#18 2021-04-02 07:17:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#19 2021-04-02 07:18:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#20 2021-04-02 07:19:00       NA                <NA>                <NA>
#21 2021-04-02 07:20:00        2 2021-04-02 07:20:00                <NA>
#22 2021-04-02 07:21:00        2                <NA>                <NA>
#23 2021-04-02 07:22:00        2                <NA>                <NA>
#24 2021-04-02 07:23:00        2                <NA>                <NA>
#25 2021-04-02 07:24:00        2                <NA>                <NA>
#26 2021-04-02 07:25:00        2                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:25:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You may stick to your nice `seq.POSIX` approach. Use `by` to follow a split-apply-combine approach. For each event id calculate the sequence. Triple the result and, using `match`, set additional values to `NA` in the old columns.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(dat, dat$event_id, function(x) {
  s1 <- s2 <- s3 <- do.call(seq, c(as.list(unname(x[-1])), "min"))
  s1[-match(x[2], s1)] <- NA
  s2[-match(x[3], s2)] <- NA
  data.frame(event_id=as.integer(x[1]), start_time=s1, end_time=s2, record_time=s3)
}))
res
#      event_id          start_time            end_time         record_time
# 1.1         1 2021-04-02 07:00:00                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:00:00
# 1.2         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:01:00
# 1.3         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:02:00
# 1.4         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:03:00
# 1.5         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:04:00
# 1.6         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:05:00
# 1.7         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:06:00
# 1.8         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:07:00
# 1.9         1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:08:00
# 1.10        1                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:09:00
# 1.11        1                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:10:00 2021-04-02 07:10:00
# 2.1         2 2021-04-02 07:20:00                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:20:00
# 2.2         2                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:21:00
# 2.3         2                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:22:00
# 2.4         2                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:23:00
# 2.5         2                <NA>                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:24:00
# 2.6         2                <NA> 2021-04-02 07:25:00 2021-04-02 07:25:00
```